# Alternative for infer_types in read_html using Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have used pandas `read_html` many years ago prior to v15.0 making use of the option of `infer_types=False` as seen in the [v12.0 documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.12.0/generated/pandas.io.html.read_html.html).

Obviously the support for this has been [discontinued](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html).

Here is an example I now face:

```
>>>import pandas as pd

>>>html1 = '<table> <thead> <tr> <th>C1</th> <th>C2</th> <th>C3</th> </tr> </thead> <tr> <td>$1.0</td> <td>1G</td> <td>50.0</td> </tr> <tr> <td>$73.0</td> <td>2</td> <td>94.0</td> </tr> </table>'

>>>html2 = '<table> <thead> <tr> <th>C1</th> <th>C2</th> <th>C3</th> </tr> </thead> <tr> <td>$4.0</td> <td>1</td> <td>42.0</td> </tr> <tr> <td>$33.0</td> <td>2.2</td> <td>50.0</td> </tr> </table>'

>>>df1 = pd.read_html(html1)

>>>df1[0].dtypes
0     object
1     object
2    float64

>>>df2 = pd.read_html(html2)

>>>df2[0].dtypes
0     object
1    float64
2    float64
```

As you can see the trouble I am having happens in the column C2. In `df1` the column dtype was parsed as an `object` (due to the presence of the G in 0th index) and in `df2` the column dtype was parsed as an `int64` (due to the presence of the decimal places).

The solution I have come up with is:

```
df1 = df1.astype("object")

df2 = df2.astype("object")
```

The issue I'm having with this solution is that if I have an `int` as well as a `float` in a column I want to preserve the `int` but `read_html` automatically infers the int value as a float and when I change the `dtype` of the column to a `str` or `object` the fact that number was an `int` fails to revert back to that in string format.

My question is, how do I head html and place restrictions on data types from versions later than 17.0 in Pandas.